# what does k[:0] means, if k is an empty list

Tags: python, list, listview, python-3.7, object-slicing

I want to know what does list[:0] means. In the following code what it is doing?

```
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
k=[]
while len(k) < 20:
    for i in LETTERS:
        k[:0] = i

print(k)

# k = ['Z', 'Y', 'X', 'W', 'V', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

- Shouldn't the loop break when `len(k)==20`?
- If `k[:0]` is an empty list, why every time there isn't a list inside k??
- Does `k[:0]` works like a stack and pushes the older items?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: `k[:0]` has a different meaning in a slice assignment than a slice expression.

Comment: Your loop doesn't break because it runs the full ```for``` loop once and then checks the length of ```k```.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a weird one here. And hard to explain.

`k[:0]` is always talking about the empty range at the start of the list. In fact any slice of an empty list is an empty list.

Because it's a slice, it is iterable, although without any elements. Like setting multiple variables at once, it can be set to an iterable, but not single values.

```
k[:0] = '123'  # puts '1', '2', '3' at the start
k[:0] = 123    # TypeError
```

The while loop doesn't really do anything, because the for loop runs through everything in `LETTERS`, and then breaks the condition.

The steps in your program are:

1. Initialise an empty list
2. Set the empty range at the start of the list (`[]`) to ['A']
3. Repeat for all other letters.
4. The list is now 26 elements long, so we don't get to the next iteration of the while loop.